# Mobile App connect to backend on premmise using Azure VPN

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-vpn

I have a mobile app, that I want to use to securely consume an API endpoint that is located on premise server.

Is it possible to do it using Azure Application Gateway and VPN? And what VPN? is it site to site or point to site?

Comment: Why would you want to use a VPN for this? Isn’t that a bit overkill of a design? What if your users end up in a jurisdiction where the use of VPNs or the underpinning encryption technology is outlawed or aggressively filtered? Why not just stand up a publicly-facing API that authenticates users and proxies the requests into the network from the public Internet? What’s your threat model that plain old TLS doesn’t cover, exactly?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to do it using Azure Application Gateway and point to site VPN. You can use [Open VPN protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about#protocol) to connect from Android, iOS (versions 11.0 and above). You can follow [this blog](https://subhashvasarapu.medium.com/connect-azure-point-to-site-vpn-to-android-device-4200579e7acb) for any additional details on implementation, which uses Point Site VPN to connect using a android device. You can also refer to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways#planningtable) for additional help on making this decision.